# getview and getcount is called cycle times,i use custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

alright,I use a custom ListView,and the listview has 202 items.when load the ListView,it will take too much time.About 6~7 seconds.I white System.out.println in getView() method. Then the getView run 202 times, after that the getView again run 202 times.For a while,the getView run 
Cycle operation 5 times.
here is my listview layout xml

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/djrwxm_scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <com.joinbright.util.NoScrollListView
                android:id="@+id/djrwxm_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:dividerHeight="0dip"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:listSelector="#00000000"
                android:padding="1dip" />
        </ScrollView>
```

here is my custom ListView java class

```
public class NoScrollListView extends ListView
{
public NoScrollListView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public NoScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public NoScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int expanSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expanSpec);
}
}
```

my custom Adapter code

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    List<Bundle> newsItems;

//      private LayoutInflater mInflater;



    public Bundle map = new Bundle();


    private List<String> spinnerList = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    private List<String> clfsspinnerList = new ArrayList<String>(3);

    private ArrayAdapter<String> djjladapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> clfsadapter;
    private int index = -1;
    private boolean ifload = true;
    public ListViewAdapter(List<Bundle> cList)
    {
        this.newsItems = cList;
        spinnerList.add("");
        spinnerList.add("zc");
        spinnerList.add("yc");

        clfsspinnerList.add("");
        clfsspinnerList.add("wxcl");
        clfsspinnerList.add("jdcl");
        clfsspinnerList.add("zrqx");
//          mInflater = (LayoutInflater) DjrwxmActivity.this
//                  .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        System.out.println("getCount()::::"+newsItems.size());
        return newsItems.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        System.out.println("getItem()::::");
        return newsItems.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        System.out.println("getItemId()::::");
        return position;
    }
```

and here is my getView method

```
     @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("//*******************************************************************      //");
        System.out.println("getView =========：：：" + position + "convertView:: " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        ViewHolder holder = null;
            try {
            map = newsItems.get(position);
                if (convertView == null) {

 //                 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_djrwxm,
 //                         null);
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listitem_djrwxm,
                        null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.djrwxm_sbguid = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_sbguid);
                holder.djrwxm_djzq = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_djzq);
                holder.djrwxm_sfdj = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_sfdj);
                holder.djrwxm_guid = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_guid);
                holder.djrwxm_djdx = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_djdx);
                holder.djrwxm_sbmc = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_sbmc);
                holder.djrwxm_rwzt = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_rwzt);
                holder.djrwxm_djnr = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_djnr);
                holder.djrwxm_djbz = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_djbz);
                holder.djrwxm_djjl = (Spinner) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_djjl);
                holder.djrwxm_ycsm = (EditText) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_ycsm);
                holder.djrwxm_cljg = (EditText) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_cljg);
                holder.djrwxm_clfs = (Spinner) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_clfs);
                holder.djrwxm_bz = (EditText) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.djrwxm_bz);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
            djjladapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DjrwxmActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
            djjladapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            clfsadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DjrwxmActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, clfsspinnerList);
            clfsadapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            holder.djrwxm_djjl.setAdapter(djjladapter);
            holder.djrwxm_clfs.setAdapter(clfsadapter);
            holder.djrwxm_djjl.setPrompt("请选择点检结论：");
            holder.djrwxm_djjl.setSelection(1);
            holder.djrwxm_clfs.setPrompt("请选择处理方式：");
            final ViewHolder queholder = holder;
            holder.djrwxm_djjl
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        public void onItemSelected(
                                android.widget.AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                            if (arg2 == 1) {
                                queholder.djrwxm_clfs.setClickable(false);
                                queholder.djrwxm_ycsm.setEnabled(false);
                            } else {
                                queholder.djrwxm_clfs.setClickable(true);
                                queholder.djrwxm_ycsm.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                            // arg0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        public void onNothingSelected(
                                android.widget.AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // arg0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
            holder.djrwxm_clfs.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case 0:
                        Spinner ss = (Spinner) v;
                        ss.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            String sbmc = newsItems.get(position)
                                    .getString("sbmc").toString();
                            String djdx = newsItems.get(position)
                                    .getString("djdx").toString();
                            String sbguid = newsItems.get(position)
                                    .getString("sbguid").toString();


                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                                Intent i = getIntent();
                                String rwid = i.getStringExtra("rwid");
                                if (position == 3) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            DjrwxmActivity.this,
                                            DjqxActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("sbmc", sbmc);
//                                      intent.putExtra("djdx", djdx);
                                    intent.putExtra("sbguid", sbguid);
                                    intent.putExtra("rwid", rwid);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    overridePendingTransition(
                                            R.anim.zoom_enter,
                                            R.anim.zoom_exit);
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent) {
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            sitbopedjrwxmdao = new sITbOpeDjrwxmDaoImpl(DjrwxmActivity.this);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String rwid = intent.getStringExtra("rwid");
            String djdx = map.getString("djdx").toString();
            Bundle bundle = sitbopedjrwxmdao.getneirong(djdx, rwid);

            holder.djrwxm_sbguid.setText(map.getString("sbguid").toString());
            holder.djrwxm_djzq.setText(map.getString("djzq").toString());
            holder.djrwxm_sfdj.setText(map.getString("sfdj").toString());
            holder.djrwxm_guid.setText(map.getString("guid").toString());
            holder.djrwxm_djdx.setText(map.getString("djdx").toString());
            holder.djrwxm_sbmc.setText(map.getString("sbmc").toString());
            holder.djrwxm_rwzt.setText(map.getString("rwzt").toString());
            holder.djrwxm_djnr.setText(map.getString("djnr").toString());
            holder.djrwxm_djbz.setText(map.getString("djbz").toString());

            if (bundle != null) {
                if ("1600801".equals(bundle.getString("djjl"))) {
                    holder.djrwxm_djjl.setSelection(1);
                } else if ("1600802".equals(bundle.getString("djjl"))) {
                    holder.djrwxm_djjl.setSelection(2);
                }
                holder.djrwxm_ycsm.setText(bundle.getString("ycsm"));
                holder.djrwxm_cljg.setText(bundle.getString("cljg"));
                holder.djrwxm_bz.setText(bundle.getString("bz"));
                if ("1601601".equals(bundle.getString("clfs"))) {
                    holder.djrwxm_clfs.setSelection(2);
                } else if ("1601602".equals(bundle.getString("clfs"))) {
                    holder.djrwxm_clfs.setSelection(1);
                } else if ("1601603".equals(bundle.getString("clfs"))) {
                    holder.djrwxm_clfs.setSelection(3);
                }
            }
            final String djbz = holder.djrwxm_djbz.getText().toString();
            holder.djrwxm_djbz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int[] location = new int[2];
                    v.getLocationInWindow(location);
                    int x = location[0];
                    int y = location[1];
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("djbz", djbz);
                    bundle.putInt("x", x);
                    bundle.putInt("y", y);
                    showDialog(1, bundle);
                }
            });

            holder.djrwxm_cljg.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        index = position;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (index != -1 && index == position) {
                holder.djrwxm_cljg.requestFocus();
            }
            if (position == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            } else {
                if (position % 2 == 0) {
                    convertView
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.xml.xml_list_shape_blue);
                } else {
                    convertView
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.xml.xml_list_shape_hui);
                }
            }
//          } catch (Exception e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }
        if (!ifload) {
            ifload = true;
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

the last is my logcat out

```
11-05 17:20:32.800: I/System.out(20354): 调用了getCount()::::202
11-05 17:20:32.800: I/System.out(20354): 调用了getCount()::::202
11-05 17:20:32.831: I/System.out(20354): 调用了getCount()::::202
11-05 17:20:32.831: I/System.out(20354): 调用了getCount()::::202
11-05 17:20:32.831: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:32.831: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：0convertView:: null type = 0
11-05 17:20:32.901: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:32.901: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：1convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{41dc55b8 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:32.956: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:32.956: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：2convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{41dc6048 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:33.003: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:33.003: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：3convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{41dc9770 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:33.050: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:33.050: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：4convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{41dcc7a0 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:33.097: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:42.105: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：198convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{42aa8ad0 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:42.144: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:42.144: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：199convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{42ab8928 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:42.183: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:42.183: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：200convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{42ac89a0 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:42.230: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:42.230: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：201convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{42ad8b38 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:42.269: I/System.out(20354): 调用了getCount()::::202
11-05 17:20:42.269: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:42.269: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：0convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{42ae8cd0 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:42.339: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:42.339: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：1convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{41dc55b8 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
11-05 17:20:42.394: I/System.out(20354): //*******************************************************************//
11-05 17:20:42.394: I/System.out(20354): getView =========：：：2convertView:: android.widget.TableLayout{41dc6048 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} type = 0
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the viewholder part? They are very important!

Comment: paste the adapter pls there may be bug

Comment: As @LawrenceChoy said, commenting out the viewholder part will not recycle cells which in terms of performance is very bad. Please post your adapter.

Comment: @Lawrence Choy  I just do a test

Comment: @TonyStark I have submit the custom Adapter code,please help me

Comment: @HpTerm Actually, I one-time Load all the data into the memory,so when I scroll the screen, the viewholder just not work

Comment: hi shaojinli are you there

Comment: Why are you using a custom `ListView`? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Your way of using Listview is simply not the correct way. Read @DavidWasser answer and comments.

Comment: @TonyStark oh,I am here

Comment: @DavidWasser Before I don't use the custom ListView.When the ListView display in the screen.Only ten item in the screen,and only ten data in the memory,the other views aren't in memory,then when i save the data in listView,it just save only ten data to the sqlite.so...

Answer (score 1):

You have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. This is bad. The `ListView` already knows how to scroll, so there is a conflict. For the surrounding `ScrollView` to know how to scroll, it needs to ask the `ListView` how big the entire content is. For the `ListView` to know how big the entire content is, it will need to call `getView()` on each and every element. You definitely do not want to do this.

Comment: hi @david wasser we can also use the listview inside the scrollview if we have a minute tweak for better performance

Comment: @TonyStark I don't understand your comment. My understanding is that `ListView` has been highly optimized. Maybe you just aren't using it properly? Have a look at [this very good video from Google I/O on `ListView`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: user had expected to load the listview fully in the first run .. For that this concept is good ...

Comment: If you want to do that, you shouldn't be using `ListView` in my opinion. `ListView` is optimized to recycle the item views. If you aren't doing that, you don't need a `ListView`. Just write your own.

Comment: what would be other option david

Comment: Why would you create more than 200 item views and keep them in memory? What is the point of that? `ListView` will show far better performance because it recycles a handful of item views and also has some tricky optimizations to improve the scrolling behaviour. I see no benefit to this approach. It is bad programming IMHO.

Comment: Thanks david ... but i looked after the user idea hence i approached my way ... your opinion is nice

Comment: +1 I agree with what David says. Listview is optimized to recycle itself. Loading everything at startup is not a correct way of using a Listview. If that's really what the user want, he better use scroll view with linear layout implemented by hand. But once again listview is here to handle a list of things and should be used correclty.

Comment: @DavidWasser I load the 200 item views to the memory,because I want to update the data in sqlite,and then save all data. If I use the listView,when save the data,it only save the Data is displayed in the screen.But the other data is not in memory.

Comment: Then your architecture is broken. You can store the data in memory if you really need to, but not the `View`s. The `View`s take up a lot more memory than the data.

Comment: @TonyStark well,the android docs said that,but if i use the listview directly,i can not save all the data in listview.

Comment: @shaojinli I think you don't understand how listview work. The list of data is different than the view. You can store in a one-time load the data in the list of data. Then, link this data to the listview, and the listview will handle how the data is displayed, will recycle the cells, etc. What you are trying to do now is save the data in the view, which is wrong.

Comment: For example, in one of my apps I have a text search. During the search I have something that make the user wait (progress bar, separated thread). Then, when all my data is fetch I notify the listView of the change and voilà. The listview handle the display. Do you get the point ?

Comment: @TonyStark Yes Yes,That's what I think,I just want to load the listview fully in the first run in memory,In order to i can update the data and save.

Comment: @HpTerm your opinion is that use the linearlayout in the scrollview?

Comment: @HpTerm I think you says that use the notifyDataSetChanged() method, is?but the listview do not need to render?

Comment: Well, for now I am not sure to understand clearly what you are trying to do. But, loading the data one-time is not a problem. You load it (prior to displaying anything) then linking your data to the listview and/or calling notifydatasetchanged. But do not store the data in the view (what you are currently doing)

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with using `ListView` for what you are doing. You can keep the data in memory in your adapter (if you want). When the data is changed, you change the data in the adapter. The adapter is the link between the `ListView` and the SQLite database. Whenever you change the underlying data in the adapter, you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` which tells the `ListView` that it needs to refresh the items that are on-screen.